# How to properly subclass SeekBar in MonoDroid?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.android, seekbar

I'm currently having a issue with the SeekBar class in MonoDroid.

Currently I have extended it like this:

```
 public class TTSeekBar : SeekBar, ITTComponent
    {
        public TTSeekBar(Context context): base(context)
        {

        }

        private int _min = 0;
        public int Min { get { return _min; } set { _min = value;} }

        public override int Progress
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Progress + _min;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Progress = value;
            }
        }

        public override int Max
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Max + _min;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Max = value + _min;
            }
        }

        public object GetInputData()
        {
            return (this.Progress + _min).ToString();
        }
    }
```

But whenever I try to create a object using `TTSeekBar _seekBar = new TTSeekBar(this);` (where `this` is a Activity) I get a `Sytem.NotSupportedException` thrown at the constructor with the message

> Unable to activate instance of type TTApp.TTSeekBar from native
>   handle 44fdad20

Extending other components of the `Android.Widget` namespace like this seems to work just fine, so I'm wondering why this one doens't work.

Comment: I think there are some other constructors you can explicitly implement, have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this on API Level 8 and it seems to work.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace AndroidApplication1
{
    [Activity(Label = "AndroidApplication1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };

            var seekbar = new TTSeekBar(this);

            var ll = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LinearLayout);

            ll.AddView(seekbar);
        }
    }

    public class TTSeekBar : SeekBar
    {
        protected TTSeekBar(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        public TTSeekBar(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public TTSeekBar(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
        }

        public TTSeekBar(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
        }

        private int _min = 0;
        public int Min { get { return _min; } set { _min = value; } }

        public override int Progress
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Progress + _min;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Progress = value;
            }
        }

        public override int Max
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Max + _min;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Max = value + _min;
            }
        }

        public object GetInputData()
        {
            return (Progress + _min).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

So as I said you just need to implement the right constructors and it should work just fine.

There is an explanation as to why here: [MonoDroid: Error when calling constructor of custom view - TwoDScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593022/monodroid-error-when-calling-constructor-of-custom-view-twodscrollview)

Comment: Thank you! Implementing the other constructors worked perfectly.